# Why does Windows 10 not reflect partition resize I did in gparted?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, gparted

I am trying to give Windows 10 more space on my 256GB SSD by expanding into unused space which I previously use for linux.

You can see the partition map as windows sees it in the screenshot.

The weird thing is that I rebooted into a mint linux live session and used gparted to resize the C: drive partition into the Unallocated area. In gparted the operation completed fine, and the map looks like you'd expect - the unallocated space has been given to the windows partition.

If I try and extend the partition in the windows Disk Management tool, it looks as per the second screenshot. I think I'd expect that as the disk is mounted and in use as the windows OS partition.

Any ideas how to extend this please?

---

**Edit**: Macrium Reflect shows that gparted extended the NTFS partition (3rd screenshot), but the usage 221/237GB is not correct - should be 118GB less than that, as I extended into unallocated space.

C: partition map in Windows.
[image: C: partition map in Windows.]

Extend Volume Wizard.
[image: Extend Volume Wizard.]

View in Macrium Reflect.
[image: View in Macrium Reflect.]

Comment: OK, well weirdly it works now. Lots of free space. In between there was a BSOD, a few scary boots into the Automatic Repair tool. In the end I used that to boot off an old W10 installation on another disk. Rebooted after going in there, and all good. But unsettling.....

Answer (score -1):

Why did not you use the Disk Management tool of Windows to perform an extend directly? Why use `gparted` for that?

It's sound like you resized the partition with gparted but the file system is still not correctly resize with the new size. It's for that you have this view in your second screenshot.

Try to extend partition directly on Windows instead of use `gparted`. Windows should extend `NTFS` at the same time. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/extend-a-basic-volume) is the documentation.

**Caution:** Do not perform any action before backup your data or perform an image disk.

Comment: I tried to use gparted because the DM tool would not do the resize. Prior to and post using gparted it reported the maximum available space as 121GB, as per the 2nd screenshot.

Comment: Do you have an error message or something else when you try to extend through DM ?

Comment: It just won't let you do it. No error message. You can see in the dialog.

Comment: @swedishhh - That screenshot seems to only be half the dialog. Doesn’t matter this is the reason you don’t use Linux tools to manage Windows partitions.

Comment: There's no more information to be had on that dialog - its as far as it lets me go. gparted saved me here because windows wouldn't let me do the resize. I've done it many times before without issue.

Comment: @swedishhh That times you did it using GParted that way with impunity were the times you could've (and arguably *should've*) do it with Windows' own Disk Management tool. The time you can't do it in Windows and you should be able to do that under normal circumstances, for whatever reason, it's the time when you should **troubleshoot** the problem, NOT force the operation using Linux tools.